# Network Theory: Laplacian, Incidence Matrix, or what else?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, matrix-equations, network-flow, graph-laplacian

Considering the following graph with 3 nodes and 3 edges which I ran into:

[image]

what is the definition, in Graph Theory, of the **L matrix**? Is it the *Laplacian* or the *Incidence Matrix*? Or is it derived from something else?

This of course is a flow study problem.

Comment: I think that it is neither the laplacian or the incident matrix..

Comment: That is a weighted Laplacian where you take the weights to be the reciprocals of the lengths.

Comment: Note though that by convention in graph theory the Laplacian would be the negative of that (i.e. it would have positive diagonal entries and negative off-diagonal entries). Thus the graph theory convention is backwards from the differential equations convention.